# "This is test order, You will not be charged" Error

Tags: in-app-purchase

I added IAP(In-App-Purchasing) in my App to remove ads, I tested it with Google Test Account as mentioned by Google.
Testing worked well and I was able to make Test purchases and Consumed the Item properly.

During Test Purchases, Google Shows that "This is test order, You will not be charged". This message is expected in Test purchases and I was not charged.

Finally I published it on Google Play and Removed Test Account from Google Dev Console.
When i installed update version from Google after 2 hours of publishing and tried to purchase, it is again saying the same msg "This is test order, You will not be charged"

Issue:-
I want it to do real purchase now. 
I have removed the Test Account from Google dev console as well.
My Google Dev Console ID and Device Registration ID(Gmail Id's) are different.

Shall I wait for some more time? 
It has been 2 hours so far I published the updated version.
Please suggest.

Comment: Did you figure out the solution to this? I'm having the same problem with my app, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ensomniac.glint

Comment: This question has already been answered at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595650/android-beta-testers-this-is-a-test-order-you-will-not-be-charged/25953299#25953299