# This is a test order, you will not be charged

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Even after the app is published, when beta testers click to purchase a product, they see the message "This is a test order, you will not be charged"

I've removed the google groups from beta but still. What should be done? They cant buy normally

[image]

Comment: Find a solution for this besides going live?

Comment: This is happening live

Comment: did u get a solution??

Comment: I am also facing same issue, anyone please let me know where to add(paste) Google billing key (MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEF.........)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Was having the exact same issue until I realized this isn't about being in beta or not. For me it was about migrating from IAB v2 to v3. Specifically the accounts you have added in your 'Play Console > Settings > Account details > Gmail accounts with testing access'. I had accounts in there long before alpha/beta was possible. After removing them + 3 hours or so to propagate, the testing message stopped showing.

Might be documented in the v3 in-app billing somewhere but I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play has changed since this was first answered.

You can now find the setting at

Settings->Developer Account->Account Details->License Testing