# Google Play Console this is a test order, you will not be charged

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-console, google-play-billing

I published my application to Play Console and I added Inn App Purchasing System. Everything is okay but when I want to buy an item, Google Play say "This is a test order, you will not be charged!" I want to buy with real payment, not test! How can I fix this problem! Thanks!
(I use Unity Game Engine) (I published to Production, not alpha, beta or anothers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This is a test order, you will not be charged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595650/this-is-a-test-order-you-will-not-be-charged)

Comment: Unfortunatelly! This doesn't work. I opened account details, there is no gmail account with testing access section or licance testing section. Probably these sections don't appear from me because I published my app to Production, not test, alpha or etc. Thanks for replay